# console.log only in development mode Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, console

I have `console.log` messages in `Angular 2 app`. I want to have `console.log` in `dev` but not in `production` So I have created `Logger service` as below:

`logger.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class LoggerService {
  log(msg): void {
    if (!environment.production) {
      console.log(msg);
    }
  }
  error(msg): void {
    console.error(msg);
  }
  warn(msg, options): void {
    if (!environment.production) {
      if (options) console.warn(msg, options);
      else console.warn(msg);
    }
  }
}
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';   
import { LoggerService } from './shared/services/logger.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'web-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {    
  constructor(private _logger: LoggerService) {
    _logger.log("This is my test logger !!");
  }   

}
```

I have questions about this approach :

- In `Dev` all the message getting logged from `logger.service.ts` file which is correct but it making debugging hard to find actual logging place (file, line no). [ In my case I have `logger.service.ts` file but in `console` it showing another file name ]

  [image]

Any suggestion on this please ?

Comment: You might be interested by this logger library: https://github.com/noemi-salaun/ng-logger#readme. It does exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Instead of using your environment variable, use the boolean `import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';`. About your question : logs are just logs without trace. If your looking to see where it has been called, you should use `console.debug`, which contains a stack trace (and gives you the ability to see where it has been called before your service)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach is just add an extra layer of delaing with console object and you need to inject the logger service in every component and make the debugging harder , but you can simply disable console object by change the log, error , warm property and freeze the object so it 's become unchangeable

consider this

*main.ts*

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();

  let disFunc = () => 'console has been disabled in production mode';

  console.log = disFunc
  console.error = disFunc
  console.warn = disFunc

  Object.freeze(console);

}
```

this way you just use console object normally.